# Generate Signed Apk does not show under "build"

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, google-play, key

I am trying to upload my first app in the playstore. I tried to get the key for Play App Signing, but I can not find "Generate Signed Apk" under "build" in Android Studio.

Because of that I generated the key with the terminal (like here: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android), but when I try to upload this key in Play App Signing it shows that this is not the right key type.

Can somebody explain what went wrong with the key I generated with the terminal or where I can find "Generate Signed Apk" so I can user the function "export encrypted key for enrolling published apps in google play App Signing" as shown here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign_release

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this issues

Generally, it happens because of configuration is correct.

Please check and follow steps:

1. Project sync successfully.
2. You need to restart your project (invalidate cache and restart) or import your project again, wait for notices for a possible needed update ie: SDK, sdk tools etc.
3. You have to wait till it be synced successfully.

Once all steps done then option will be visible for generate signed apk.

thanks

Comment: Could you please explain the first and third step detailed? I know how to invalidate cache and restart the application, but this does not change anything.